# Реализация баланса в Telegram-боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При создании Telegram-бота на Python столкнулся с проблемой баланса пользователя. Каким образом можно каждому пользователю сделать баланс, или переменную с балансом?
Чтобы, к примеру при изменении баланса одного пользователя не менялся баланс второго и т.д.
Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: база данных, не?

Comment: Сделайте для каждого пользователя отдельный баланс

Comment: Как пользоваться базой данных?

Comment: Делать для каждого пользователя баланс - это бессмысленно

Comment: С Sqlite начните

Answer (score 1):

Если пользователей немного и вы хотите только протестировать функционал, самым простым вариантом будет хранить словарь (`dict`), где ключом будет ник пользователя, а значением — баланс. Словарь можно периодически синхронизировать с диском, например, каждые несколько минут, а также при запуске и выходе.

Для более серьёзных проектов нужно будет работать с базой данных. В Python уже есть библиотеки для работы с SQLite, MySQL и другими системами, попробуйте поискать и выбрать ту, которая больше подходит под вашу задачу.